# Contagem regressiva PHP + Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma coluna no banco de dados chamada `time`, ela possui um evento que faz o seguinte:

```
UPDATE users SET time = time - 1
```

Como padrão recebe 1800 segundos (30 minutos) certo?

Agora eu queria *recuperar* o tempo que vai decaindo tentei o seguinte:

```
<?php
$database = new DB;

/*Selectiono meu usuário*/
$select = $database->select($username);

/*Aqui retorno tudo*/
$fetch = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*Aqui imprimo na tela o conteúdo do campo time*/
echo $fetch['time'];
?>
```

Agora tentei fazer o seguinte, pra recuperar, mas não aparece. Ou seja, não funciona.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.contagem').css('display', 'block');
    $('.contagem').html("<?php echo $fetch['time']?>");
});
```

Da erro na primeira linha:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Revirei este site e nada me ajudou.

**Edit**

Código todo

```
<?php
$database = new DB;

/*Selectiono meu usuário*/
$select = $database->select($username);

/*Aqui retorno tudo*/
$fetch = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*Aqui imprimo na tela o conteúdo do campo time*/
echo $fetch['time'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Contagem
    </title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<span class="contagem" style="display: none;"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.contagem').css('display', 'block');
        $('.contagem').html("<?php echo $fetch['time']?>");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Obs: Ao chegar ao **0** dar um reload na página.

Comment: Esse código jQuery está no arquivo PHP ou em um arquivo JavaScript separado? Ele precisa estar no arquivo PHP para que o trecho de código PHP seja interpretado. Se estiver no arquivo JS, o PHP nunca verá esse trecho de código, embora o efeito que eu vejo disso seria exibir o código PHP no elemento `.contagem` ao invés do valor propriamente dito.  Tem como colocar seu código completo e a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Cara, faz uma requisição ajax, eu particularmente odeio esse tipo de abordagem que mistura os 2.
Fica bem mais limpo

Comment: Matheus, não é read() mas sim ready()

Comment: Se você está aplicando esses estilos logo quando a página é carregada pode fazer isso diretamente no HTML do documento sem precisar de script algum. Ajude o seu navegador :)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, está no mesmo arquivo, o código todo é este mesmo, não tem mais nada. claro abre e fecha tags `PHP` e `script` claro.

Comment: Bom mas eu queria contagem em tempo real, decrescente entenderam?

Comment: Se é em tempo real, o mais fácil será fazer a contagem apenas com JavaScript, utilizando a função `setTimeOut` ou `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peguei este código nesta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20618517/2993657) no SO em inglês. Como não é possível interpretar php no snippet abaixo, coloquei o valor fixo de 180 segundos (3 minutos).

```js
/* Código exposto em uma página php */
//var contador = '<?php echo $fetch['time']?>'; /**** Variável do PHP ****/
var contador = '180';

/* A partir daqui, pode ficar em um arquivo .js */
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      location.reload();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var count = parseInt(contador),
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(count, display);
};
```

```html
<div>Registros terminam em <span id="time">Carregando...</span>!</div>
```

Comment: opa vou testar parece ser útil.

Comment: Funcionou perfeito...

Comment: Que bom que deu certo ;) Pontos pro SO em inglês :P

Comment: percebi que ao chegar a -1 começa um loop de erros no console tem como resolver isto? tipo o tempo chegar a -1 no caso minha query na pergunta. ao chegar -1 voltar pra 0

Comment: @MatheusBorjes, ali no código coloquei pra dar um reload na página caso o contador chegue a ficar abaixo de 0. Para lhe auxiliar, poste a mensagem de erro do console para entender o que ocorreu.

Comment: veja: http://prntscr.com/g3v4zf

Comment: Nesta linha "display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds" ele tenta setar o conteúdo do html, o que está ocorrendo é que o objeto "display" não existe, pode ser que tenha sido removido do HTML, neste caso, faça uma validação se ele é nulo e caso não for, aí sim atualize o texto. O  document.querySelector pode ser alterado para jQuery caso desejar, não tem nenhum problema. Ficaria $("#time") em vez de  document.querySelector("#time").

Comment: Resolvido valeu.

Answer (score 2):

O erro da primeira linha é pq voce colocou o read..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
}
```

Imagino que você está no mesmo arquivo do php, quando lança aquele `<?php` dentro do $('.contagem'), correto?

Para validar o tempo, crie um setInterval, e quando chegar no 0, você dispara o reload da página.

```
    segundos = <?php echo $fetch['time']?>;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(segundos > 0)
          segundos = segundos - 1;
        else
          location.reload();

        $('.contagem').html(segundos);

    }, 1000/*a cada segundo, esta func vai rodar*/);
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: A resposta do amigo ali em cima, me ajudou mas obrigado ok +1 pra vc tbm

Answer (score 1):

Fiz esta alteração para mostrar o tempo em segundo no ato e redirecionar para uma pagina especifica.

```html
<h1>Nada foi encontrado no servidor</h1>
<div id="msg"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var tempo = 100; 
  setInterval(function(){
   if(tempo >0){
     tempo = tempo-1;
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Voce será redirecionado em "+tempo+" segundos";
    if(tempo==0){  
   window.location.href = 'login';    
 }
   }
  },tempo);
 
</script>
```

var tempo = 100;    
  setInterval(function(){
         if(tempo >0){
             tempo = tempo-1;
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Voce será redirecionado em "+tempo+" segundos";
            if(tempo==0){       
            window.location.href = 'login';             
    }
         }
        },tempo);