# Evento de update do MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query

[Fiz esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225903/contagem-regressiva-php-javascript) ontem, consegui a resposta que eu queria, vou ser direto e reto:

Tenho a query:

```
UPDATE users SET time = time - 1
```

`time` é do tipo `int` e recebe como valor padrão `0`, no meu código PHP eu fiz um esquema onde o usuário clica no botão adiciona `1800` no valor do `time` e o evento da query ali em cima entra em ação, acontece que quando chega no 0 começa contar -1,-2,-3...-1800 etc, queria fazer travar ao chegar no 0

Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer de duas formas a meu ver.

1. Fazer o update sempre que a cláusula WHERE retornar true para a condição `time > 0`. Exemplo: `UPDATE tabela SET time = time - 1 WHERE time > 0`.
2. Atualizar sua tabela para que o campo `time` tenha o atributo `UNSIGNED`. Isso quer dizer que seu campo só poderá ter número não-negativos, de acordo com a documentação do MySQL. Exemplo: `ALTER TABLE tabela MODIFY COLUMN time int(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL`.

**Veja:** [UNSIGNED e ZEROFILL: Para que servem as colunas no MySQL](https://dicasdephp.com.br/unsigned-zerofill-mysql/)

Comment: Obrigado salvou minha vida e a do meu irmão kkkk ele ta criando um site e eu outro, detalhe: deixei como `UNSIGNED`